# React Native WebView not working IOS simulator

Tags: react-native, webview

Does the WebView work in IOS simulator?

The code below does not return an error, but also doesn't display anything.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native';

class MyTest extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default MyTest;
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native Webview not loading any url (React native web view not working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451139/react-native-webview-not-loading-any-url-react-native-web-view-not-working)

Comment: try <WebView .... style={{flex:1}}/>

Comment: @JamesLiu, I tried, but still not working.

Comment: @KacperWiszczuk looks like the link you sent there is no solution for the question

Comment: WebView work well in my simulator.  My code:<WebView 
    useWebKit={true}
    style={{flex:1}} 
    source={{uri:url}} 
    startInLoadingState={true} 
    renderLoading={()=>(<ActivityIndicator size='large' color={COLOR_STANDARD} style={{marginTop:100}} />)}></WebView>

Comment: Awesome @JamesLiu. Could you please post your solution? I would like to accept it as a solution for the question

Comment: Lol... If you add a container to wrap the web view, it stop working

Comment: Related:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451139/react-native-webview-not-loading-any-url-react-native-web-view-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebView work well in my simulator. My code:

```
<WebView 
useWebKit={true} 
style={{flex:1}} 
source={{uri:url}} 
startInLoadingState={true} 
renderLoading={()=>(<ActivityIndicator size='large' color={COLOR_STANDARD} 
style={{marginTop:100}} />)}>
</WebView>
```

Comment: 1. add border to check the real size of the web view.
2. check log to see something wrong
3. use safari(dev version) to check the web render process.

Comment: I create a pastebin (https://pastebin.com/gPttXuei) to check the code, I just create a loading state when the webview is not completed.

Comment: updated I create snack (snack.expo.io)

https://snack.expo.io/@mrvictoria/webview-test

Answer (score 1):

I want to contribute here for those getting white screen on ios. First the webview is inside scrollview because I have other content. I know it is adviced for webview not to be inside any component. I was battling this for weeks until I came upon [James Liu's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995785/james-liu). I was running it on expo client (ios) and was getting white screen. Here is my code before I saw his answer.

```
    contentContainerStyle={{
          flexGrow: 1,
      }}>

    <WebView
         ref={ref => (this.webview = ref)}

    source={{uri:  currentSite}}

    style={{  height:550}}

    scrollEnabled={true}
    startInLoadingState={true}


    onNavigationStateChange={this._onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
    javaScriptEnabled = {true}
    domStorageEnabled = {true}

    startInLoadingState={false}
    onLoad={() => this.hideSpinner()}

    injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
    onMessage={event => {

    //Html page
    const wishData = event.nativeEvent.data;
     this._getProductName(wishData);
     this._getProductPrice(wishData);

    }}

  />
  </ScrollView>
```

All I needed to add is useWebKit={true} and from the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/webview#usewebkit) it says:

useWebKit->If true, use WKWebView instead of UIWebView. And this props is ios specific. Furthermore, I googled and found that WKWebView is more recent than UIWebView ( I don't know more about this).

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was to wrap my component that returned my WebView in a View with a set height OUTSIDE the file with the component that returns my WebView.

The wrapper View with the height should be in the file that component with the WebView was imported into.
It took several takes and prayer but I finally found it out muahahaha!

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is in the property `startInLoadingState`, you have to set this to true:

```html
<WebView 
    startInLoadingState={true} />
```