# how to fix react native webview error code -2

Tags: react-native

i'm trying to use WebView but cant work that out

```
export class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}} />
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Webview not loading any url (React native web view not working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451139/react-native-webview-not-loading-any-url-react-native-web-view-not-working)

Comment: thanks for help but i found my problem, it doesnt work on emulator but it works perfectly fine on my device